# How to save and load configuration data of type sequence

Tags: configuration

I have a theme "basic_theme". I want to add some settings to this theme, in particular config menu_search_fields is a sequence of data, each entry has 3 informations (field, weight and uuid).

I'm pretty sure the schema is correct because I almost copied from `core\modules\image\config\schema\image.schema.yml`

```
basic_theme.settings:
  type: theme_settings
  label: Basic theme settings
  mapping:
    menu_search_fields:
      type: sequence
      label: Menu search fields
      sequence:
        type: mapping
        mapping:
          field:
            type: string
          weight:
            type: float
          uuid:
            type: string
```

Inside theme-settings.php I have some fields to map to those data, for example field "field" is:

```
$i = 0; // for this example only one entry
$form['menu_search']['fields']['wrapper'][$i]['field-wrapper'][
    "menu_search_fields.$i.field"
] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Field'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting(
        "menu_search_fields.$i.field"
    ),
];
```

I used as a key "menu_search_fields.$i.field" but i doesn't work.

How can I correctly map the fields with sequence entries?

Comment: `["menu_search_fields.$i.field"]` this key value that you have looks a bit weird, not sure if you actually need that as you already registered the iteration of the sequence in `[$i]`. Much of this comes down to transform your data before loading it in as default value and before storing it in config.

Comment: For simple data (like string) I used as key value the name of the key in the mapping section like
`mapping:
    container_class_toolbar:
      type: string`
It worked that way, without transforming the data.